# how Can I enable modal property(Enable Keyboard Control) in Simple Modal Confirm Override from Eric Martin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have exiting code for Simple Model and it is working fine but now I want to that code (Model) 508 competent. I am using Eric Martin's Confirm Override Model. Is there any way that I can enable Tab key only for model?
Thanks in Advance.